# how to show the error message

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

i want to insert the details when click on button in that time i want to validate and same time i want o show the error message on top.

I am validating but i not able to show the error message where exactly getting problem i not fining any one please help.

```js
$(document).on('click', '#button', function () {
 var FirstName=$('#fName').val();
 alert(FirstName);
 var LastName=$('#lName').val();
 
 
  if(FirstName.val() == '') {
   alert("kk")
   $("#error").append("Please eneter First Name");
     }
     else if(LastName.val() == '') {
         alert("k")
   $("#error").append("Please eneter Last Name");
     }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
     <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>SSSIT</title>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
      <!--
       <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.png">
       <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="images/apple-touch-icon.png"> 
      -->
      <link href="jqueryMobile/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
      <script>window.$ = window.jQuery = WLJQ;</script>
      <script src="jqueryMobile/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js"></script>
     </head>
     
     <body style="display: none;">
      <div data-role="page" id="page">
    <div data-role="header" id="header" data-position="fixed">
     <h3>Softpath Technologies</h3>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content" style="padding: 15px;margin-top:21px">
     <p id="error"></p>
     <label for="text">First Name:</label>
      <input type="text" name="text" id="fName">
     <label for="text">Last Name:</label>
      <input type="text" name="text" id="lName">
     <a href="" data-role="button" id="button" onclick="dtlsSubmit()">SUBMIT</a>
  </div>
    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" id="footer">
     <h3></h3>
    </div>
 </div>
      
      
      
      
      <script src="js/initOptions.js"></script>
      <script src="js/main.js"></script>
      <script src="js/messages.js"></script>
     </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it should be

```
if(FirstName == '') {
    alert("kk");
    $("#error").append("Please eneter First Name");
}
else if(LastName == '') {
    alert("k")
    $("#error").append("Please eneter Last Name");
}
```

Also you may need to return false in case of error otherwise you will never see the error message appending in your `<p>` tag.

The code should go like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '#button', function() {

    var FirstName = $('#fName').val();

    alert(FirstName);
    var LastName = $('#lName').val();
    var valid = 1;

    if ( FirstName == '' ) {
        alert("kk")
        $("#error").append("Please eneter First Name");
        valid = 0;
    }
    else if ( LastName == '' ) {
        alert("k")
        $("#error").append("Please eneter Last Name");
        valid = 0;
    }
    if ( !valid )
        return false

    return true;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `FirstName` instead of `FirstName.val()`. Because of with line `var FirstName=$('#fName').val();` you have already assigned value to `FirstName`, and while accessing `FirstName.val()` must be giving you error (Check console in Developer tools).

Consider following snippet:

```
if(FirstName == '') {
    alert("kk")
    $("#error").append("Please eneter First Name");
}
else if(LastName == '') {
    alert("k")
    $("#error").append("Please eneter Last Name");
}
```